# Why POST API request not working from browser but working fine on Postman? Throws AssertionError in browser to call is_valid() before accessing .data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Ok, Here's the problem: I have created a POST API in Django REST framework & I want to add logged-in user to request.data when making POST request & `It works perfectly fine when I create post calling this API from Postman`, but when I visit the post create API endpoint from browser it throws `AssertionError:` '''When a serializer is passed a `data` keyword argument you must call `.is_valid()` before attempting to access the serialized `.data` representation.
You should either call `.is_valid()` first, or access `.initial_data`'''.
Here's the snippet of my get_serializer method which i use to override & add user to request.data:

```
class PostCreateView(CreateAPIView):

serializer_class = PostSerializer

def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
    kwargs["context"] = self.get_serializer_context()
    request_data = self.request.data.copy()
    request_data["user"] = self.request.user.id
    kwargs["data"] = request_data
    return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)

def post(self,request):
    serializer = self.get_serializer()
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    status_code = status.HTTP_201_CREATED
    response = {
        'success' : 'True',
        'status code' : status_code,
        'message': 'Post created successfully',
        'post_detail': serializer.data,
        }
    
    return Response(response, status=status_code)
```

Update: I have changed my code in post method to pass user initially in a Post instance & then pass it in PostSerializer as: `serializer = self.serializer_class(post, data=request.data)` & it works on both Postman as well as browser's DRF request. But I'm curious to know why my above code with `get_serializer` method gave me AssertionError from browser's DRF request? but worked fine when making a POST request from Postman.